# Using R to randomly pair elements not in the same group

Tags: r, algorithm

I'm writing an algorithm in R to randomly pair people up but people in the pair cannot be from the same group (team).

I've started by creating an nxn matrix of all of the people. I've marked 0 to indicate people that cannot be paired together (if they are in the same team) and 1 otherwise.

**The problem:**
I now need to sample from the list of eligible people (all of the 1s) in each row, and make a note of the pairing and make sure that the two people in that pair cannot now be paired with another person.

e.g.

Name - Team

A    - 1

B    - 2

C    - 3

D    - 4

E    - 1

F    - 2

G    - 1

```
  A B C D E F G
A 0 1 1 1 0 1 0
B 1 0 1 1 1 0 1
C 1 1 0 1 1 1 1
D 1 1 1 0 1 1 1
E 0 1 1 1 0 1 0
F 1 0 1 1 1 0 1
G 0 1 1 1 0 1 0
```

I realise that this algorithm may get stuck if we get to a stage where nobody can be matched together, so I was thinking of incorporating a timer to restart when the algorithm has been running for say 5 minutes.

Happy to consider any other matching algorithms that you think may be more suitable.

I've already had a look at similar problems on stack overflow (e.g. [Sampling column values in a matrix, without replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651171/sampling-column-values-in-a-matrix-without-replacement)) but none of them seem to address the problem of not pairing people from the same group.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
 (!tcrossprod(table(df1)))+0L
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"), 
Team = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), .Names = c("Name", "Team"),
 class =  "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Hi akrun. Thank you for your fast solution.  I've tried the line of code you have suggested, but it's returning a 2x2 zero matrix. I used my nxn matrix in place of 'df1' in your solution so that my line of code looks exactly like '(!tcrossprod(table(matrix)))+0L'. Is this what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @annievic Updated with the data I used.  It won't work with more than 2 columns.  This is one of the reasons why a better example is needed rather than a simple case.

Comment: Thank you. That's a much more efficient way to generate the matrix than the way I was previously using. The question I really need to answer though is how to find random pairings (making sure people from the same team are not paired together) once I have this matrix. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: @annievic Sorry, I thought this was the expected output.  Could you update your post with the expected output or better would be to ask as a new question as more people will look into it.